# Can I obtain some land on lease from the government to do some livestock farming?

Tags: immigration, canada

I am planning to immigrate to Canada.

My primary aim is to have some diploma in livestock farming.

After finishing my diploma, Can I obtain some land on lease from the government to do some livestock farming?

Which province would be best for farming and agriculture?

Comment: What makes you think the Government (as opposed to private individuals / companies) would have farmable land available to lease? Do you have a source/reference for this scheme?

Comment: @Gagravarr,  Canada is a huge country and most of the landmass is uninhabited. So, logically, all land can't be held privately.

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed a vast swath of Canada which is *crown land*. Most of it is in the North of the country. According to this [web site](http://www.thecanadianencyclopedia.ca/en/article/crown-land/) it is indeed more than 90% of the land. But bear in mind that most if it is either forest, tundra or ice.
The province of Ontario maintains a [web site](https://www.ontario.ca/page/buy-or-rent-crown-land) which gives your more information.
The interesting part of the text might be this:

> Crown land is no longer actively marketed, rented or sold for private
>   recreational or residential use.

EDIT:

Using search engines revealed several sources. It definitely seems that you have to go to the provinces. [Saskatchewan](https://www.saskatchewan.ca/business/agriculture-natural-resources-and-industry/agribusiness-farmers-and-ranchers/crown-lands/lease-crown-land) and [Manitoba](http://www.gov.mb.ca/agriculture/land/crown-land/index.html) have at least the subject of land lease for agriculture on their web sites.

It seems you have to be Permanent Resident or Citizen to farm here.

Comment: But the use contemplated in the question is neither recreational nor residential, so this doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: Interesting comment, have you had a look at the page from the Ontario government? If so you'd have noticed that there is a list of conditions which qualify an individual for the transfer of crown land. I couldn't find anything which included agriculture but perhaps you'll have more luck. I provided a link so that anonymous and everybody else who'd care to read can make up his own mind.

Comment: I suspect that agriculture falls within "commercial purpose," but I don't really know.  I added my comment because those who are moving too quickly to follow the link might conclude from your answer -- as I initially did -- that crown land is not available, period.  Only after I looked a second time, noticed "recreational or residential," and followed the link, did I see that crown land does seem to be available for commercial and industrial use.

Comment: I'm curious whether it is still possible to get land for agricultural purpose from the government. It sounds like the settlers of the 1800s. There first European settlers here where I live were Mennonites from Pennsylvania. They bought the land from a British officer in England who in turn got it from the First Nation.